# Why does my flip animation not work in chrome and safari?

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

My first time post. 
Sorry if my code is a bit messy, I am still a beginner and I have been trying to make this flip animation work on chrome and safari. It works on firefox but I cannot figure out why the flip animation doesnt work correctly on chrome.

```js
function flip(){
  document.getElementById('card').classList.toggle('flip');
}

function flip2(){
  document.getElementById('card2').classList.toggle('flip');
}

function flip3(){
  document.getElementById('card3').classList.toggle('flip');
}
```

```css
h4{
 font-size: 2em;
}

#week-wrap {
 height: auto;  
 max-width: 100%; 
 width: auto; 
 background-color: #efefef;
 text-align: center;
}


#card, #card2, #card3 {
 text-align: center;
    position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
   max-width: 30%;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin: 1%;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;  
  transition: all 1s ease;
  
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
 backface-visibility: hidden;


 border-style: solid; 
    
}

#back{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  
   
  position: absolute; 
  
  color:white;
  background-color: teal;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
}

#back{
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
   
   
}


.figcaption {
 text-align: center; 
    width:100%; 
  height:0;
 font-size: 4em; 
  line-height: 0;
 color:white;
    position:absolute; 
  top:10%;
    z-index:1;
}

#card img {
 -webkit-display:block;
    display:block;
    
    max-width: 100%; 
}

#card2 img {
    display:block;
    max-width: 100%; 
}

#card3 img {
    display:block;
    max-width: 100%; 
}

.flip{
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  
    
}
```

```html
<div id="week-wrap">

<div id="card" onclick="flip()">
 <div class="figcaption">Front</div>
 <img src="http://www.petakids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Baby-Bunny.jpg" />
  <div id="back"><h3>Back</h3>
  </div> 
  
</div>
    
    <div id="card2" onclick="flip2()">
 <div class="figcaption">Front </div>
 <img src="http://www.petakids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Baby-Bunny.jpg" />
      <div id="back"><h3>Back</h3>
  </div> 
        
      
</div>
      
       <div id="card3" onclick="flip3()">
 <div class="figcaption">Front </div>
 <img src="http://www.petakids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Baby-Bunny.jpg" />
         <div id="back"><h3>Back</h3>  </div> 
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: _"why it doesn't work on chrome"_ Can you describe "doesn't work"?

Comment: Let me answer what does not work. "You do not see the back of the cards in Chrome"

Comment: Set a z-index on the back. You have three elements with the same id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a z-index on back, get rid of the same id and make it a class.

```js
function flip() {
  document.getElementById('card').classList.toggle('flip');
}

function flip2() {
  document.getElementById('card2').classList.toggle('flip');
}

function flip3() {
  document.getElementById('card3').classList.toggle('flip');
}
```

```css
h4 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
#week-wrap {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
#card,
#card2,
#card3 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 30%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 1%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-style: solid;
}
.back {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  background-color: teal;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#card img {
  -webkit-display: block;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#card2 img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#card3 img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.flip {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="week-wrap">
  <div id="card" onclick="flip()">
    <div class="figcaption">Front</div>
    <img src="http://www.petakids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Baby-Bunny.jpg" />
    <div class="back">
      <h3>Back</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="card2" onclick="flip2()">
    <div class="figcaption">Front</div>
    <img src="http://www.petakids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Baby-Bunny.jpg" />
    <div class="back">
      <h3>Back</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="card3" onclick="flip3()">
    <div class="figcaption">Front</div>
    <img src="http://www.petakids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Baby-Bunny.jpg" />
    <div class="back">
      <h3>Back</h3> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And after that you are going to say that you can not click the backside to flip back. That has something to do with the `backface-visibility: hidden;` rule.